# how to install turtle with python3 on linux

Tags: python-3.5

when I install turtle,meet some problem like this :

[image]

My python version is 3.5.2 and OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Did you try to `import turtle` ? As I know `turtle` should be already installed with Python3 and you don't have to install it. As I know Ubuntu 16 removed `tkinter` module which `turtle` may use so you have to install `python-tk`

Answer (score 8):

```
apt install python3-tk
```

It is tested and works perfectly on Linux Mint and Ubuntu...

Edit:

The reason is because turtle is based on tkinter, for example:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you ask for `Turtle` to draw `forward`, `left`, etc.

It is already installed with Python. You don't have to install it. Probably You may have to install `python3-tk` using `pip3 install python3-tk` or rather `apt install python3-tk`

---

See

```
pip search turtle
```

part of result

```
turtle (0.0.2) - Turtle is an HTTP proxy whose purpose is to throttle connections to
                 specific hostnames to avoid breaking terms of usage of those API
                 providers (like del.icio.us, technorati and so on).
```

You try to install some `HTTP proxy`

`except ValueError, ve:` is correct syntax in Python 2 but not in Python 3.

Comment: pip install python3-tk fails: "Downloading/unpacking python3-tk
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python3-tk
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python3-tk
Storing debug log for failure in /home/follinge/.pip/pip.log"

Comment: @FrederickOllinger read my answer - `python3-tk` is NOT python module but linux module and you have to use `apt` (on Ubuntu/Mint) or similar tool to install it. BTW. on python3-tk should be preinstalled and you can check it in python using `import tkinter`

Comment: It was also already bundled with Python3 for me. My OS is Debian testing (Bookworm).

Answer (score 2):

I was am using Ubuntu 18.10 and recently after configuring Python 3 as my default environment I got the same error. 
I used this command to reconfigure it and it worked.

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

Success!!

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install python-tk
```

then go to python shell and type

```
from turtle import*
fd(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error but on Mac os and I tried to update my python via brew. This fixed my problem.
Firstly, give brew permission to access your shared files,

```
sudo chown -R $(whoiam) /usr/local/share
```

This was for another problem with brew :D, you can test the next command and use this only if you need to.
Finally,

```
brew upgrade python3
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me. I am using Pop Os 22.04. Type these commands on the terminal. Hope this will for for you as well.

To install the current version of Python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

To install the pip package manager:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Run the below command in the terminal to install the Turtle library

```
sudo pip3 install PythonTurtle
```

To verify the installation:

```
python3 -m pip show PythonTurtle
```